# Start a process in a new window from a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have written a batch file (.bat) in windows. I want to execute a particular process in a new window. How do I do this?

Example

```
a.py -s 3 -l 5
b.py -k 0  -> I want to start this in a new window and let the original batch file continue 
C:\program.exe
...
....
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use the start command:

```
start foo.py
```

or

```
start "" "c:\path with spaces\foo.py"
```

Answer (score 9):

> start "title" "C:\path\to\file.exe"

I would highly recommend inserting a title so that you can call that title later via the TASKKILL command if needed.

> TASKKILL /im title

Comment: `TASKKILL /IM title` doesn't work for me... or doesn't work anymore. The closest I could find was `TASKKILL /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq title"` and that only works on processes where setting the title actually sets the window title. It won't work on Windows apps such as notepad.exe.

Comment: You probably need to use `/F` and `/T` switches. `/T` is for killing child processes and `/F` is for force.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions below are for calling multiple files in the same window; this question has been answered already so I am just adding my 2 cents.

If you are working with a master batch file that calls multiple other batch files, you would use the "call" command.  These aren't processes, though.

Within the other batch files you can call the "start" command to start them in separate windows.

master.bat

```
call myCoolBatchFile1.bat
call myCoolBatchFile2.bat
call myCoolBatchFile3.bat
```

If you are using Windows Powershell, you can use the Start-Process command.

myPowershell.ps1:

```
#silent install java from java exe. 
$javaLogLocation = "[my log path here]"
$javaFileName = "[javaInstaller file name here].exe"
$process = "$javaFileName"
$args = "/lang=1033 /s /L $javaLogLocation"
Start-Process $process -ArgumentList $args -Wait
```

For more info on the start command and its usages, as well as other scripting tech:
https://ss64.com/nt/start.html

Answer (score 0):

As per the requirement, we can follow up like this. As I was doing an automation work for my office purpose. So I need to create a process for a certain time, & after that I have to kill the service/ process. 
So What I did, 
For start a process:

```
**`start "API" C:\Python27\python.exe`**
```

Then I tried with my all other works & tasks. After that I need to kill that process. So That I did,

```
**`taskkill /F /IM python.exe`**
```

After killing the process, outcome ran smoothly.