# When running a .bat file with Start-Process

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

When I run this .bat file directly it does what its supposed to do. When I use start-process, a black window opens and then closes right away.

```
Start-Process \\server01\f$\filelocation\myfile.bat -Verbose -NoNewWindow
```

Any ideas why it doesnt run?

Here is what is inside the batch script.

```
MediSpan.Install.exe /Autostart:DEV_Medispan_Data
```

Comment: There is probably an error in `myfile.bat`, but you haven't shown us that, so we're as stuck as you are. Also, since you've commendably obfuscated the path and filename, we can only speculate - if either contains separators, then "quoting the full filename" thus: `"\\server01\f$\filelocation\myfile.bat"` may assist.

Comment: Running external commands/executables from PowerShell, they must be properly formatted for execution. [• PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)

Comment: There are no errors when I run the batch file directly. it does exactly what its supposed to when its ran directly.

Comment: If I remove the -nonewwindow it prompts me to run the batch script, I hit ok then it just closes. I've ran other script like this before and never had an issue like this so I assume its something I'm just forgetting to do.

Comment: PowerShell does only runs .ps* files. .bat/cmd are ran by cmd.exe. not PowerShell. Running what you are doing (without Start-Process), is just calling cmd.exe under the covers. When using Start-Process you are bound by its particulars. You are also using Start-Process and using -NoNewWindow. So, you are specifically asking PowerShell not to show you anything. So, how do you know if the command actually ran, if you are hiding the results? You are not showing what is in the.bat, so, we have no idea what is expected.

Comment: This type of question has been asked before all over the web and right here on SO see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645326/safest-way-to-run-bat-file-from-powershell-script.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306412/start-a-process-in-a-new-window-from-a-batch-file. So, your question could be seen as a duplicate.

Comment: @postanote I know its running based on 1. Its in taskmanager, and 2. I see when the application opens a connection to the DB.

Comment: I'm going to assume that your batch file ends with an `Exit` command, which should be changed to `Exit /B`, or `GoTo :EOF` instead.

Comment: It sounds to me like your `myfile.bat` script is running to completion and exiting. What makes you think it's not running? I would try running the batch script with `%comspec% /k scriptFile`, then the console window won't disappear on you.

Comment: This is all thats in the batch file MediSpan.Install.exe /Autostart:DEV_Medispan_Data

Comment: Okay, you're just arguing with the people who are trying to help you. Was MediSpan installed? If not, were there any error messages or logs? The way you launch the app, there's no reason for the window to hang around after the application runs.

Comment: Lastly, if you are just running that executable from PowerShell, why are you using a .bat at all. Just call the executable directly, including any switches needed, using the methods shown in the first TechNet link I posted for you.

Comment: Again, if you don't cause the console window to remain open, you can't read any error messages that might have appeared in that window. Until you cause it to remain open or a find a log file laying around somewhere, all we can do is guess that there was some kind of failure. The fact that it succeeds under some circumstances, gives us some clue that it can at least do it's job correctly under those circumstances, but does not help you or us diagnose the failure that you are interested in resolving.

Comment: @postanote start-process 'F:\SWDATINSCD_AN_19000101\MediSpan.Install.exe' "/Autostart:DEV_Medispan_Data" it doesnt seem to take the options. Any ideas?

Comment: Using the call operator is a better option. See my update for your use case. Yet, if you are set on Start-Process, you could see my update for you. See my second update.

Comment: @postanote that did it thank you.
& "F:\SWDATINSCD_AN_19000101\MediSpan.Install.exe" '/Autostart:DEV_Medispan_Data'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending my comment:

```
# Simple batch file
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\abc.bat'
echo off
cls
echo Hello

# Run the .bat file
D:\Temp\abc.bat
# Results - no window is seen unless you are really paying attention since it will flash very fast
<#
Hello
#>

# Using the call operator vs Start-Process
& 'D:\Temp\abc.bat'
# Results - same window response as above
<#
Hello
#>


Start-Process -FilePath ' D:\Temp\abc.bat' -Wait
# Results  - same window response as above
<#
no results are displayed
#>

Start-Process -FilePath ' D:\Temp\abc.bat' -PassThru
# Results  - same window response as above - But this shows it ran
<#
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    19       3     1536       2524       0.00  10160  11 cmd
#>

$A = Start-Process -FilePath ' D:\Temp\abc.bat'-PassThru;$A.ExitCode
$A
# Results  - same window response as above - But this shows it ran
<#
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
            0        0          0       0.02  19128
#>
```

If you want to see what the .bat did, then you have to have a pause in the .bat...

```
echo off
cls
echo Hello
pause
```

Calling and 3rdP executable from PowerShell, from the TechNet link.

> 5. The Call Operator &
>
> Why: Used to treat a string as a SINGLE command. Useful for dealing
> with  spaces.
>
> In PowerShell V2.0, if you are running 7z.exe (7-Zip.exe) or another > command that starts with a number, you have to use the command invocation operator &.
>
> The PowerShell V3.0 parser do it now smarter, in this case, you don’t need the &  anymore.
>
> Details: Runs a command, script, or script block. The call operator, also known as the "invocation operator," lets you run commands that are stored in variables and represented by strings. Because the call operator does not parse the command,  it cannot interpret command parameters
>
> Example(s):

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe' "c:\videos\my home video.avi" /fullscreen
```

Things can get tricky when an external command has a lot of parameters or there are spaces in the arguments or paths!

With spaces, you have to nest Quotation marks and the result is not always clear!

In this case it is better to separate everything like so:

```
$CMD  = 'SuperApp.exe'
$arg1 = 'filename1'
$arg2 = '-someswitch'
$arg3 = 'C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt'
$arg4 = '-yetanotherswitch'
 
& $CMD $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4
```

or same like that:

```
$AllArgs = @('filename1', '-someswitch', 'C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt', '-yetanotherswitch')
& 'SuperApp.exe' $AllArgs
```

For Start-Process, as per the same TechNet link.

```
($p = Start-Process -FilePath 'F:\SWDATINSCD_AN_19000101\MediSpan.Install.exe' -ArgumentList '/Autostart:DEV_Medispan_Data' -wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru)
$p.HasExited
$p.ExitCode
```